# Open a photo that has been passed between activities in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have a custom camera app with two activities. The first activity (`MainActivity`) allows the user to take a photo with a custom camera. I would like to open this photo in the second activity (`DrawActivity`) so that the user can eventually draw on it. My `MainActivity` works great, the camera opens, snaps and saves the image to the phones external storage. I am having trouble with the `DrawActivity` opening the photo. I am passing what I believe to be the Uri of the image from my `MainActivity` to my `DrawActivivty` with the following code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DrawActivity.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("mybitmap",values.toString());
                    startActivity(myIntent);
```

Where *values* are defined (before I create the above intent):

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    fout.write(ostream.toByteArray());
                    fout.close();
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
                            System.currentTimeMillis());
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

I can not get the `DrawActivity` to display the photo. I set up a Toast message just to see what my `DrawActivity` was receiving, and I got this [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVfmN.png). I set up the toast code with this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String imageuri = extras.getString("mybitmap");
Toast.makeText(this, imageuri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and try to pass it to my image view with:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(imageuri));
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

When I pull up the photo properties in the stock photo app on my phone the image path is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGuAe.png). Am I passing the wrong information? Too much information? Am I parsing the passed information incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the values which is not the `imageUri`, and you can get the bitmap from the image path. So, pass the file path only from your `MainActivity` to `DrawActivity`. After passing the path, you can get the `Bitmap` by the following code.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thank you Nigam. I was able to figure out my issue. I was sending too much/redundant information to my DrawActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Rob i suggest you this kind of User friendly architecture. Because going to another activity is ok but if you can do everything in the same activity like this is good approach as i know.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response Zumry. I figured out my issue, I was sending redundant information to my DrawActivity.